# How to compare values between rows

Tags: excel, vba

I need help here. I have a spreadsheet that has more than 6K datas. I need to compare the values between the "**MOVE_IN_QTY**" and "**MOVE_OUT_QTY**" by using VBA. The problem here is I need to compare the value right after the code has changed from "**CV64**" and "**TW78**" in the code column. The value I have higlighted in red and the code I have highlighted in blue and yellow. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please include the code you are trying to use in your question and explain the problems you are having with it.

Comment: BTW it looks as though you could do this by formula as well. Are you just looking for those two specific codes (CV64 and TW78) or any change of code? Is the whole thing repeated on different Product ID's ?

Comment: Hi @braX actually I have tried to code it but I didn't have any idea how to come with the solution because it's quite complicated, I need to compare the data between rows but different column. This is my first time I have encountered this kind of problem.

Comment: Hi @TomSharpe no. That codes are for that product id only, other product id has different codes. Hmm

Comment: The best way would be to set the range you are evaluating as a variable, then offset that variable and evaluate a different column, this way you could go about without defining the columns, but since i don't know the real layout I set the columns to be hardcoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a few assumptions here:

1. Move In & Move Out are always numbers.
2. Move numbers are compered using the =,<,> process.
3. Unknown further action based on result is required.

Also it helps to include what you have tried and what is not working.

> ```
> Sub ReviewData()
>
> Dim wkbk As Workbook
> Dim xsheet As Worksheet
> Dim codeColumn As String, moveIN As String, moveOUT As String
> Dim rowCount As Double
>
> Set wkbk = ThisWorkbook
> Set xsheet = wkbk.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'change sheet name here
> codeColumn = "B" ' change column letter here
> moveIN = "C" 'set move in column
> moveOUT = "D" 'set move out column
>
> 'this will loop through the Code column until the last set of data.
> rowCount = xsheet.Range(codeColumn & xsheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
>
> For x = 2 To rowCount
>     'checks if code transitions from one code to another
>     If not xsheet.Range(codeColumn & x).Value = xsheet.Range(codeColumn & x + 1).Value Then
>
>         If xsheet.Range(moveIN & x).Value = xsheet.Range(moveOUT & x + 1).Value Then
>             'do something if the code is the same
>         Else
>             xsheet.Range(codeColumn & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
>             MsgBox ("Row: " & x & " is different") 'comment this out not to get the message
>         End If
>     Else
>     End If
>
> Next x
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: Hi Ricards, thank you for answer. But my problem here is I want to know if the value of the "Move_Out_Qty" is the same with the "Move_In_Qty" bcs it is supposed to be the same right after the code has changed from "CV64" to "TW78". I need to trace it if they have different values between the "MOVE_IN_QTY" at "CV64" and "TW78", actually TW78 is the turning point between the "MOVE_IN_Qty" of "CV64" and "Move_Out_Qty" of "TW78".In the real spreadsheet, it has more than 600 product ids.And also the code is different for other product ids, but the turning point is right after the code has changed.

Comment: So before I change the answer I wanted to check that I understood it correctly. When the Code switches to TW78 MOVE_OUT should match CV64 MOVE_IN correct?

Comment: Hi Ricards, it's working well, but may I know how can I detect which rows that shows different values? Bcs I got the They are different message but I don't know which row is that.

Comment: I updated to message Row number and also to highlight red, you can comment out the MsgBox using ' if you dont want to see it, also do mark the answer complete if this is working for you.

Comment: Update to look at the Code and validate any time the code changes.